# Confusion between mongoose.connection() and mongoose.createConnection()

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've been studying mongoose for three days and I'm a bit confused about the use of these two methods (i know that "mongoose.connection()" will be deprecated in the future...)

The problem is: when I'm trying to convert (from "mongoose.connection()" to "mongoose.createConnection()") the action.js file of this example https://gist.github.com/2785463 it seems to not work for me...

there's my code...

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
db = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', 'test');

db.on('error', function () {
  console.log('Error! Database connection failed.');
});

db.once('open', function (argument) {
  console.log('Database connection established!');

  mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames(function (error, names) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('Error: '+ error);
    } else {
      console.log(names);
    };
  });
});
```

and there's my terminal output (typing "node test.js" on my ubuntu terminal..)

```
Database connection established!

/home/_user_/Scrivania/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:437
    throw err;
          ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'collectionNames' of undefined
  at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/home/_user_/Scrivania/test2.js:11:25)
  at NativeConnection.g (events.js:192:14)
  at NativeConnection.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:93:17)
  at open (/home/_user_/Scrivania/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:408:10)
  at NativeConnection.Connection.onOpen (/home/_user_/Scrivania/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:415:5)
  at Connection._open (/home/_user_/Scrivania/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:386:10)
  at NativeConnection.doOpen (/home/_user_/Scrivania/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:47:5)
  at Db.open (/home/_user_/Scrivania/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:287:14)
  at Server.connect.connectCallback (/home/_user_/Scrivania/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:235:7)
  at g (events.js:192:14)
```

Comment: [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYlfruqx_S8) is a good reference for connecting to multiple databases using `connect` & `createConnection`. Although it's in Hindi, you can follow along with the code in the video.

Comment: similar question is asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53951290/6908282

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't call `mongoose.connect()` then `mongoose.connection` doesn't contain an an open connection.  You should be using the return value from your `mongo.createConnection()` call instead (that you've saved into `db`).

So the last section of code should change to:

**UPDATED**

```
db.db.collectionNames(function (error, names) {
  if (error) {
    console.log('Error: '+ error);
  } else {
    console.log(names);
  };
});
```

I don't see a `collectionNames` method on `Connection`; looks like you have to follow properties down into the native connection object to access that (see above code).

Comment: well, when i'm trying to use **console.log(db.collections)** it prints an empty object: **{}**, but i'm sure my test db has two collections (i could verify that by the mongo shell using **show collections**). By the way i'll continue with my investigation thx for u help, for now! (and maybe sorry for my bad english :S)

Comment: @cl0udw4lk3r Updated the example now that I found how to access the [`collectionNames`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#collectionnames) method of the native driver's `Db` object from a Mongoose connection.

Comment: Nice! It works! Thanks a lot, maybe i should change the line **_db_ = mongoose.createConnection(...)** to **_connection_ = mongoose.createConnection(...)** to avoid mistakes.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, Im using the exact code as you have mentioned above, but the callback function is never getting called. If i restart the mongod process, the callback is automatically called. Why is the collectionsNames callback not called?

Comment: @rajkamal It's best to post that as a new question that includes your own code showing how you're making the connection.