# Mongo models not responding

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm working on a new app and trying to get mongo set up locally for storage. My api endpoints are getting hit but as soon as I try to actually call a db operation - find or save - it doesn't respond.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Person = require('./data/person');
var dbConfig = require('./config');
//database: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/persondb'
var db = mongoose.createConnection(dbConfig.database);
db.on('error', function() {
    console.info('Error: Could not connect to MongoDB. Did you forget      to run `mongod`?');
});

if (~process.argv.indexOf('mode_dev')) {
    global.mode_dev = true;
    console.log('Server started in dev mode.');
}


// configure app to use bodyParser()
// this will let us get the data from a POST
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', router);

router.route('/persons')
    .post(function(req, res) {
        debugger;
        var person = new Person();      // create a new instance of the Person model
        person.name = req.body.name;

        person.save(function(err) {
            debugger;
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Person created!' });
        });
    })
    .get(function(req, res) {
         Person.find(function(err, persons) {
            debugger;
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(persons);
        });
    });
```

Here's the schema:

#### data/item.js

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var personSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

I am running mongod before getting my webserver started. As soon as I get to the .save or .find calls, no error is thrown but the callbacks are never hit.

Comment: What happens when you do console.log(req.body) in your post? do you get the name attribute's value?

Comment: @jackblank yes, I do. +++

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162979/confusion-between-mongoose-connection-and-mongoose-createconnection, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786374/queries-hang-when-using-mongoose-createconnection-vs-mongoose-connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would connect like this:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/persondb");

var db = mongoose.connection;
```

maybe [this](http://blog.blairvanderhoof.com/post/37309147906/why-arent-my-models-returning-from-their-queries) will help it explains problems using `mongoose.createConnection(`

> if you use createConnection, you need to always reference that connection variable if you include a registered model, otherwise if you use mongoose to load the model, it will never actually talk to your database.
>
> **The other solution is to simply use mongoose.connect instead of
>   mongoose.createConnection.** Then you can just use
>   mongoose.model(‘MyModel’) to load the requested model without needing
>   to carry around that db connection variable.

Comment: That did it... I had actually read that thread but apparently not made the right updates to use .connect. Thanks!!