# connect() vs createConnection()

Tags: mongoose

I am new to using `mongoose` and would like to know what is the fundamental difference between `mongoose.connect()` and `mongoose.createConnection()`, particularly in general what are the things to considered when using one over another.

My understanding on the official documentation is that generally when there is only one connection `mongoose.connect()` is use, whereas if there is multiple instance of connection `mongoose.createConnection()` is used.

Hope someone can clarify more about this.

Also, if my understanding is correct, what are the disadvantages of using `mongoose.createConnection()` in single connection? Why it is not advisable that we use `mongoose.createConnection()` for every case to standardize the connection?

Comment: I found some answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786374/queries-hang-when-using-mongoose-createconnection-vs-mongoose-connect

Comment: You can find more details here, https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4700#issuecomment-260226027

Comment: [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qYlfruqx_S8) is a good reference for connecting to multiple databases using `connect` & `createConnection`. Although it's in Hindi, you can follow along with the code in the video.

Answer (score 36):

> My understanding on the official documentation is that generally when there is only one connection mongoose.connect() is use, whereas if there is multiple instance of connection mongoose.createConnection() is used.

Yes. To be exact, `.connect()` creates actually a pool of sockets/connections (defined in `poolSize` in the connection settings, the default is 5) it keeps open, so there is actually multiple connections, but in a single pool.
That being said, if you want multiple connections pools, with different properties, you should use `createConnection`

> Also, if my understanding is correct, what are the disadvantages of
> using mongoose.createConnection() in single connection? Why it is not
> advisable that we use mongoose.createConnection() for every case to
> standardize the connection?

This is a good question and there's also already an answer in the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections):

> > Mongoose creates a default connection when you call mongoose.connect(). You can access the default connection using mongoose.connection.

Basically `.connect` is a shorthand for a set of (mostly) best practice settings for `createConnection`

In most simple projects, you needn't worry about specifying different read or write settings, pool sizes, separate connections to different replica servers etc., that's why `.connect` exists.

However, if you have more demanding requirements (e.g. for legal or performance reasons), you will probably have to use `createConnection`.

A couple of weeks ago, I ran into a situation, where one of my (in-house) statistics packages needed database access with a sporadic, yet big load. Since I didn't want to pass the db/mongoose object down to the package to keep it as modular as possible, I just created a new connection. This worked very well, because I only needed to access a certain Model I defined in the package and not the ones defined in my "parent"-package. Since the new package only needed read-access and could read from a different slave/replica db to reduce the load on the main one, I switched to createConnection on both ends to separate the connection from the main one.

For me, the big disadvantage of creating multiple connections in the same module, is the fact that you can not directly access your models through `mongoose.model`, if they were defined "in" different connections. This answer details that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22838614/2856218

Comment: came to your same problem recently as well. but with dealing with needing to connect to more than one domain, ie 2 clusters behind distinct domains. Mongoose and MongoDB seem to be designed around a single cluster connection per process. Which lead me to test out different approaches to manage this, ie, clustering node processes, or running a microservice arch just to connect these two clusters to a single branch of my API. Have you encountered this  problem before by any chance?

Comment: I haven't had this exact problem before and I am not sure if I understood correctly, but what stops you from using createConnection like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19475270/2856218 , only with cluster-urls? https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#mongos_connections

Comment: @BenSower But that means you have to pass the conn and conn2 objects when creating a model, right? So everytime you create a new object, you have to do = new MyModelA(conn) or new MyModelA(conn2)

Comment: @FrancisZabala: Yes and no. Yes, you have to tell mongoose on which connection this model should be "registered". No, you don't pass it to the model, but create the model on the connection like this: var ModelB    = yourConnection.model('Model', new mongoose.Schema({  title :String })); As mentioned in my original comment, using mongoose.model(), is just a shorthand for registering it on the default connection created by mongoose. You can probably also do mongoose.connection.model().

Comment: What do you mean by 'object'? A model or a document? Everytime you create/register a model, you have to do it that way, yes. When creating a document, you can just directly call the Model like new Model({title: 'someTitle'}). Since the model only exists in the scope of a specific connection, it'll also only be saved there.

Comment: Thank you @BenSower. I had to make the codes work before commenting. I apologize for my confusing comment earlier. I have deleted that. I was able to make the code work using the one you suggested. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)